# How to allow reverse ssh-tunnel connection to my host on demand?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I've set up a reverse ssh-tunnel (no autossh is used right now, but I might be using it)from remote laptop to my pc, but I don't trust much the remote host, as there might be different people using it and I would like somehow to control, when remote host can connect my pc, so that I could allow or prohibit this tunnel on demand.

The problem here is also that remote laptop experiences connection issues, so I might not be able to connect to it to start ssh tunnel explicitly to allow connection to my pc, so I would like to have the tunnel run on remote laptop persistently. I use TeamViewer to connect to remote laptop to setup things.

Remote laptop is Windows with cygwin, so cygwin solution is appreciated, but a pure linux one might be helpful too, as I might ask to install some linux distro on remote machine.

Could you please suggest any solutions to these problems?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that using `-N` option for `ssh` command disables command execution, so I think no one will access my PC if ssh command is issued like that. As I force password entering when connecting, no one would seem to access my PC without reentering password even if retried to connect via the same terminal immediately after ssh session termination.
So I just need to keep ssh running and hope things are Ok.

Comments welcome, because I'm not that skilled in it.